# How can I remove the embedded building blocks (therefore reducing the file size) (while keeping the content of the building blocks) of a Word file?

Tags: microsoft-word-2010

I have several documents that have Building Blocks built in which we use frequently.  The building block/quick parts are used with the content control feature.  (Click within the paragraph, drop down box shows up and allows you to select one of 3-6 tailored boilerplate messages) Usually when sharing these with other firms, we pdf them, reducing the file size, removing the access to see the other boilerplate messages and preserving the formatting.

The original file is closer to 900kb and is a .docx format.

However we sometimes have to share the file in Word format so our clients can copy/paste our info into their own templates.  I cannot find a way to ‘clean up’ the documents so they are what a typical 1 page document should be ~ around 30kb, while keeping it in Word format.
Most of my building blocks are saved in my Normal file.

I have tried:

1. Compressing pictures – doesn’t reduce size as there is only one small photo in the documents
2. Removing hidden data – the only data that shows up when inspecting is the author information, etc., and the header footers.  Removing header footers actually removed this content from the document.  I’d like to keep them.
3. Copy/Pasting the whole thing into a new blank document.  Building blocks are retained when copy/pasting.
4. Saving as a different file format:

   1. XPS is basically like a PDF only chopped up text.
   2. OpenText Document does not reduce file size.
   3. Word document.  (saves as a docx)  Still 900kb.
   4. Word 97-2003 document.  Removed content control but its still 900kb.

Does anyone have any further suggestions?

Have I gone about programming my building blocks the wrong way?  Since multiple users access these building blocks, I programmed them into the Normal template and pointed everyone there.  It didn’t seem to work to save them in the Building Blocks file and point them there.  Content control didn’t populate the building blocks.

Comment: What do you see if you open the file with notepad? You might identify something that takes a lot of space.